# onEachFeature Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I have a leaflet map that zooms and fits on the bounds of the polygon that is clicked via onEachFeature. 
Is there a way to add  another geojson layer by clicking on the polygon? I need to zoom in and add another layer on click

```
    var polska;

    function resetHighlight(e) {
        polska.resetStyle(e.target);
        info.update();
    }

    function zoomToFeature(e) {
        map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    }

    function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            mouseover: highlightFeature,
            mouseout: resetHighlight,
            click: zoomToFeature
        });
    }

    polska = L.geoJson(exp_polska, {
        style: style,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run that code inside of zoomToFeature, the function that is called on click.

```
    function zoomToFeature(e) {
      map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
      L.geoJson(polska2, {
        style: myStyle2,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
     }).addTo(map);
    }
```

See a fiddle here, [load a 2nd layer on click of 1st layer](https://jsfiddle.net/tlohnes/ysjws766/)